# Wordpress multiple loops and general loop

Tags: php, wordpress

I need creating custom multiple loops for my blog home.php in order to show 3 different content layout of defined category then proceed with the general loop excluding posts ID within the first 3 loops.

So far I made the the 3 different content layout of defined category `category_name=arts`:

```
<?php $posts = get_posts('numberposts=1&offset=0'); foreach ($posts as $post) : start_wp(); ?>
<?php static $count1 = 0; if ($count1 == "1") { break; } else { ?>

<?php the_title(); ?>

<?php $count1++; } ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>


<?php query_posts('category_name=arts&showposts=1'); ?>
<?php $posts = get_posts('numberposts=1&offset=1'); foreach ($posts as $post) : start_wp(); ?>
<?php static $count2 = 0; if ($count2 == "1") { break; } else { ?>

<?php the_title(); ?>

<?php $count2++; } ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>


<?php query_posts('category_name=arts&showposts=1'); ?>
<?php $posts = get_posts('numberposts=1&offset=2'); foreach ($posts as $post) : start_wp(); ?>
<?php static $count3 = 0; if ($count3 == "1") { break; } else { ?>

<?php the_title(); ?>

<?php $count3++; } ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

I did get stuck to proceed with the general loop. Any suggestions are much appreciated.

Comment: Your code is extremely slow and very very bad. You should drop `query_posts` completely, it breaks the main query object. Use `get_posts` or `WP_Query`. Proceed from there. You are also running each loop twice.

Comment: @PieterGoosen Can you share example code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have serious issues here

- For each loop you are running two queries, one with`get_posts()` and one with `query_posts`
- You are making use of `query_posts` which you should never ever use. This adds a huge overhead on your query as you rerun the main query, so you are actually running 3 queries to get 1 post for each loop. This slows your page down which costs you dearly when it comes to SEO

  Furthermore, `query_posts` breaks the main query object which breaks thousands of functions an plugins that relies on the main query object. You should really spent time and read [this post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/1753/31545) on just how really bad `query_posts` is.
- [`start_wp()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/start_wp/) was already depreciated in WordPress version 1.5. This means your code has bugs, and one should avoid bugs at all costs. You should really turn on debug while developing as debug will immediately throw a debugging message telling you that you are using a depreciated function. [Here is an article from the codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress) on how to work with the debugging feature in WordPress. You should be using `setup_postdata( $post )`
- Still on the debugging part, `showposts` was dropped in favor of `posts_per_page`
- You are running a `foreach` loop without making sure you have posts to display. ALWAYS ALWAYS make sure you have valid values before you try to do anything with a dynamic variable. This will avoid numerous bugs should your variable return an empty value.
- You should really work on your formatting as your code is quite hard to read when everything is packed into one line. Use proper indentation. Properly indented and formatted code does help a lot with readability and debugging. Also, drop the `:` and `endforeach` syntax. Although it is valid, it is not supported by code editors which make debugging a nightmare should your code fail. I always tell everyone to use the old style curly brackets as all code editors support them. They make debugging very easy
- ALWAY ALWAYS, VERY IMPORTANT, always reset custom queries. Use `wp_reset_postdata()` to reset the `$post` global whenever you call `setup_postdata()` or `the_post()` in a custom query. Just for interest, because I have already stated to never use `query_posts`, you should use `wp_reset_postdata()` to reset custom queries created with `query_posts`
- Lastly, you can do what you need with the specified category in only one loop, not three. Simply make use of your counters. If this is purely for styling, you can simply use the [`:nth child()` selector in css3](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp)

The following is untested, but you can try the following

```
$special_cat_args = [
    'category_name' => 'art',
    'posts_per_page' => 3,
    //Add extra arguments here
];
$art_posts = get_posts( $special_cat_args );

// Setup a variable to store the post ID's so we can exclude them in the 'main' query
$ids_array = [];

// Check if we have posts before we continue
if ( $art_posts ) {
    // Start our counter
    $counter = 0;
    
    // Start the loop
    foreach ( $art_posts as $post ) {
        // Setup postdata, must use $post
        setup_postdata( $post );

        // Store the post id in an array to exclude in "main" query
        $ids_array[] = $post->ID;

        // Do something separate for every post
        if ( 0 == $counter ) {
            // Do something for post one
        } elseif ( 1 == $counter ) {
            // Do something for post two
        } elseif ( 2 == $counter ) {
            // Do something for post three
        }

        // Update the counter
        $counter++;
    } //endforeach $art_posts
    wp_reset_postdata(); // VERY VERY IMPORTANT
} //endif $art_posts

// Now we can do our "main" query and exclude the three posts from the special category
$args = [
    'post__not_in' => $ids_array, // Exclude the three post from previous query
    // Rest of your arguments
];
$q = get_posts( $args );
// Run your loop
```

Comment: Thanks for your useful and informative solution. very helpful :)

Comment: My pleasure. Enjoy ;-)

Comment: Could you give me hand with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34769194/wordpress-customloop-pagination

Comment: I'm trying to do similar over here but can't figure it out.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58477455/trouble-displaying-two-woo-product-loops-on-one-page