# Wordpress custom loop pagination

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination

I coded custom loop within [multiple loops structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34691210/wordpress-multiple-loops-and-general-loop/):

```
$q = get_posts( $args );
// Run your loop
echo '<div class="row">';
$i = 0; 
foreach ( $q as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post );
  $i++; 
  if ($i%4==0)
    echo '</div><div class="row">';
  get_template_part('loop');
endforeach;
wp_bs_pagination();
wp_reset_postdata();
```

except for I added `wp_bs_pagination();` to load pagination. It only repeat the same set of posts o every page. Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you please add the `$args` array in your question? Thanks

Comment: @SaqibAmin check here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34691210/wordpress-multiple-loops-and-general-loop/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not use `get_posts()` for paginated queries. `get_posts` works well for non-paginated queries, but not paginated queries.

The issue is, `get_posts` only returns the `$posts` property from `WP_Query` and not the complete object. Furthermore, `get_posts()` passes `'no_found_rows'=> true` to `WP_Query` which legally breaks pagination.

Because `get_posts` uses `WP_Query`, we might as well use `WP_Query` which returns everything we need to paginate our query. Just remember, we need to add the `paged` parameter to the query in order to page it

We can rewrite your query as follow

```
$args= [
    'paged' => get_query_var( 'paged' ),
    // Add any additional arguments here
];
$q = new WP_Query( $args );
// Run your loop

if( $q->have_posts() ) { 

    echo '<div class="row">';
    $i=0; 

    while ( $q->have_posts() ) {
    $q->the_post();
        $i++; 
        if($i%4==0)
            echo '</div><div class="row">';

        get_template_part('loop');

    }
    wp_bs_pagination();
    wp_reset_postdata();
}
```

You will need to somehow pass `$q->max_num_pages` to `wp_bs_pagination()` to set pagination to your custom query, but I do not know the function, so I cannot give you an exact solution on this.

Comment: Absolutely useful. Thanks:)

Comment: My pleasure, enjoy ;-)

Comment: Since I stuck again, I use custom pagination where I failed to pass custom query $q to it. May you check the code http://pastebin.com/6u0nnGV9

Comment: This should work `wp_bs_pagination( $q->max_num_pages );`

Comment: O crap, I remember you said this is for a static front page. If so, and you are using WordPress 4.4.1, pagination won't work. There is a bug which will be fixed in WordPress 4.4.2. There is a patch, just google *get_query_var( 'page' ) bug trac*

Answer (score 0):

Try this, paste this in your functions.php

```
function custom_pagination() {
global $wp_query;
$big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer
$pages = paginate_links( array(
        'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
        'format' => '?paged=%#%',
        'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
        'total' => $wp_query->max_num_pages,
        'prev_next' => false,
        'type'  => 'array',
        'prev_next'   => TRUE,
        'prev_text'    => __('«'),
        'next_text'    => __('»'),
    ) );
    if( is_array( $pages ) ) {
        $paged = ( get_query_var('paged') == 0 ) ? 1 : get_query_var('paged');
        echo '<ul class="pagination">';
        foreach ( $pages as $page ) {
                echo "<li>$page</li>";
        }
       echo '</ul>';
    }
```

}

and then use the function **custom_pagination()**

Got the solution from here: http://www.ordinarycoder.com/paginate_links-class-ul-li-bootstrap/

Comment: Why not @PieterGoosen ?

Comment: See my answer. And what is a dead give away here is that you are paging the main query and not the custom query at hand ;-)